# Mathematical induction using inequalities

Tags: inequality, induction

I just started with induction and i can solve cases where you need to prove that the left hand side is equal with the right hand side. But now i am trying to do this one:

Prove that 
$$
1+1/4+1/9+1/16+ ... +1/(n^2) <  2-(1/n) 
$$
for n > 1

Base n = 2:
$$
1/4 < 2-(1/2)  <=> 1/4 < 1/2 
$$
Assume true for n = k:

$$
1+1/4+1/9+1/16+ ... +1/(k^2) <  2-(1/k)
$$

Show true for n = k + 1:

$$
1+1/4+1/9+1/16+ ... + 1/(k^2) + 1/(k+1)^2 < 2-(1/(k+1))
$$

Im stuck here, usually when i prove expressions with equalities i just rewrite 
$$
1+1/4+1/9+1/16+ ... + 1/(k^2) 
$$

in the above to

$$
2-(1/(k))
$$

But now im not sure how to continue..

Comment: As an aside, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}\approx 1.6449$, but this using this to prove it is of course overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the same as usual, i.e. substitution just instead of equality use an inequality ;-)

To be more specific, just take all what is known in one bracket:
$$\underbrace{1+1/4+1/9+...+1/k^2}_{<2-1/k}+1/(k+1)^2$$
and substitute, using "<" 
$$1+1/4+1/9+...+1/k^2+1/(k+1)^2<2-1/k+1/(k+1)^2$$

What is left, is to prove that:
$$2-1/k+1/(k+1)^2\leq2-1/(k+1).$$
Hope you can do it!

Then, combining both would give you the desired outcome.

Comment: You beat me to it!  And did a very nice job at it.

Comment: Thanks, but how come the "<" became a "<="?

Comment: @user6395724 Actually, it holds strictly. But what is *sufficient* to finish the proof is to show weak inequality, since the first one is strict. And then a<b<=c implies a<c.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing with inequalities

$1 + ..... + 1/k^2 < 2-1/k$

So $1 + ......  + 1/k^2 + 1/(k+1)^2 < 2- 1/k + 1/(k+1)^2$

Now it just a matter of showing $2 - 1/k + 1/(k+1)^2 \le 2 - 1/(k + 1)^2$

which is just a matter of showing $1/k - 1/(k+1)^2 \ge 1/(k+1)$

which is ... well lets see...:

$1/k - 1/(k+1)^2  = ((k+1)^2-k)/k(k+1)^2 = (k^2 + k + 1)/k(k+1)^2 = k(k + 1 + 1/k)/k(k+1)^2 > k(k+1)/k(k+1)^ = 1/(k+1)$

So it seems to be true.